# About the efficiency issus of Qt Graphics View Framework when there are vast items

Tags: graphics, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

Recently, i develop a new visualization software using the QT Grapohics View Framework.
In the software, we need show a lot of items, include the point and line, about ten thousand above. 
But, in the process of display , there are pool efficiency and often no response. When we want to zoom it or remove the position of scene,  we must wait a span and it hard to bear.
so, i want to know whether it is normal and  how to improve the efficiency about the situation.
Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

I use Graphics View Framework to draw geographical map (large polygons with thousands of points). And it does it very well.

In Qt-4.6 there were delays when zooming and moving around. With antialiasing enabled dealys were so long that it was better to kill the application. So try to use the **latest version of Qt**.

Also if you use custom QGraphicsItem-s check this article: [Qt: Improving QGraphicsView Performance](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2007/02/03/qt-improving-qgraphicsview-performance/).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my most serious problems with performance by:

- disabling the scrool bars (it helped a lot when zooming in/out and scrolling),
- ploting points with painter->drawPoints(pointCloud.constData(), pointCloud.size());
- disable indexing in case of moving items or enable indexing but avoiding some operations
- use cosmetic pen, 0 width or Qt::NoPen always that possible
- setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
- setViewportUpdateMode(FullViewportUpdate);